# "ip route" Commands in Dockerfile Generate Error

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I create a Docker container like this:

```
$sudo docker build -t "logstash-collector" ~/logging/logstash/

$sudo docker run -d \
--user=root \
--name="logstash-collector-01" \
--net=logging \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
logstash-collector
```

And from there I can change its default gateway to an nginx container (for transparent load balancing):

```
$sudo docker exec -it logstash-collector-01 ip route delete default
$sudo docker exec -it logstash-collector-01 ip route add default via 172.18.0.10
```

And it works, and everything's fine:

```
$sudo docker exec -it logstash-collector-01 ip route 
default via 172.18.0.10 dev eth0 
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.3
```

But when I try to automate this by putting those commands in my ~/logging/logstash/Dockerfile like:

```
FROM logstash
COPY logstash.conf /usr/local/share
CMD ["-f", "/usr/local/share/logstash.conf", "--config.reload.automatic"]
CMD ["ip", "route", "delete", "default"]
CMD ["ip", "route", "add", "default", "via", "172.18.0.10"]
```

I see them getting executed during build:
[image: Logstash container build]

But the container fails to launch.  `sudo docker logs logstash-collector-01` tells me: 
**RTNETLINK answers: File exists**

That error happens if I issue the second `ip route` command without issuing the first one (Linux won't add a route if one is already in its active routing table).  But how can this be?  Are my Dockerfile's CMD commands processing out of order?

Comment: Note: I also tested with `CMD ["ip","route"...]` vs `CMD ip route ...` syntax in the Dockerfile.  No effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you can only specify one CMD per dockerfile.

CMD is what the container will be running (which would normally be logstash, a long-running, daemon-like process), so what are you doing is *only* running the last CMD.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services#23693804

You could consider a lo-fi solution like using a single container's network to share between nginx and the logstash agents, but you then need to keep track of ports.

Higher up the chain are solutions like kubernetes that make this kind of thing easier.

In between, you might look into consul(/SkyDNS) to help with DNS discovery.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'm ending up just putting those `exec` commands into my deployment script.

Comment: Yup, that definitely works. It does mean your container now needs to start with root (which logstash alone doesn't need), but since you have capability bounding, that's not _so_ bad.